# Как изменить подсветку в web storm 2019

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

В проекте много тестовых файлов, которые web-storm почему-то подсвечивает ярким зелёным,на фоне которых остальные файлы теряются для глаза. Где можно изменить этот параметр? Мне не удалось его найти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвет можно настроить в *Settings | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors, Tests*